# SSH not working over WLAN (ssh enabled, ping works, tcpping on port 22 works)

Tags: ssh

I know this has been asked several times, but I went through a lot of trying to connect from my PC to my Raspberry Pi via SSH and I don't get it to work.

**My Setup:**

- Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+
- Working RetroPie 4.4 installation
- Windows-PC with Putty

**What I want to do:**

- Connect with Putty to my raspberry Pi over SSH
- Preferrably over wlan, but I tried both cabled and wlan

**What I tried/did:**

- Tried to connect with Putty (wlan) --> I got a connection refused error
- Enabled SSH with the raspi-config tool
- Tried to connect with Putty again -->
- [image: putty error messages]
- Tried to ping the wlan-ip: **success**
- Tried to open a telnet session on port 22: **success**
- Tried tcpping on port 22: **success**
- Despite that: still the same error.
- Connected PC over a simple switch to the pi.
- Tried all of the above with the eth0 ip with same result as wlan.

I think I can be fairly sure that the SSH server is listening (ps -ef says so, too) and a connection could be established. I do not think it is a problem of putty as i see tons of people using it with their raspberrys. I do not think it is a wlan related problem as I get the same results on the wired connection.

Could anyone point me in a direction where the error might be located?

Thank a lot.

Comment: Look at the server logs. It seems the connection is accepted and later terminated. The logs should state why that happens.

Comment: Thanks @RalfFriedl ! I checked the logs and found a solution. See my answer post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I checked the server logs and found the following error multiple times:

```
Aug 19 11:52:44 retropie sshd[9707]: error: key_load_public: invalid format
Aug 19 11:52:44 retropie sshd[9707]: error: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
```

I deleted the keys and reconfigured them:

```
sudo rm /etc/ssh/ssh_host*
sudo dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server
```

After a restart, the connection worked like a charm.